# How to reference instantiated object in [Command] function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I am currently learning to make a multiplayer fps in unity but I have got a problem. I have a `PlayerShoot` script which handles shooting different weapons and types. Here is the code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using Weapons;

public class PlayerShoot : NetworkBehaviour {
public WeaponManager weaponManager;

void Awake()
{
    weaponManager = GetComponent<WeaponManager> ();

    if (weaponManager == null)
        return;
}

void Update()
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
        return;

    // Fire
    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")) 
    {
        HandleFire ();
    }
}

void HandleFire()
{
    Weapon currentWeapon = weaponManager.equippedWeapon;

    if (!currentWeapon.CanFire())
        return;

    switch (currentWeapon.weaponType) 
    {
        case WeaponType.THROWING:
            ThrowWeapon ((WeaponThrowing)currentWeapon);
            break;

        case WeaponType.FIREARM:
            RaycastShoot(currentWeapon);
            break;

        case WeaponType.MELEE:
            AttackMelee(currentWeapon);
            break;
    }
}

// Throwing weapon
void ThrowWeapon(WeaponThrowing weapon)
{
    GameObject throwedObject = (GameObject)Instantiate (weapon.throwObjectPrefab, weaponManager.throwWeaponPlace.position,  weaponManager.throwWeaponPlace.rotation);

    Debug.Log(throwedObject);

    Rigidbody throwedObjectRB = throwedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();

    if (throwedObjectRB != null) 
    {
        throwedObjectRB.AddForce(throwedObject.transform.forward * weapon.throwForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

    CmdOnWeaponThrowed();
}

[Command]
void CmdOnWeaponThrowed()
{
    // How to access my throwed object here. 

    NetworkServer.Spawn(obj, obj.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().assetId);
}

// Raycast shooting
void RaycastShoot(Weapon weapon)
{

}

// Melle attack
void AttackMelee(Weapon weapon)
{

}
}
```

Here in the handle fire I get the equipped weapon and check its type and based on type I call method for shooting this type. In my case it is throwing the weapon. In throw weapon function I instantiate weapon prefab and then call the `CmdOnWeaponThrowed` to spawn the object in all clients. So my problem is I cannot access the throwedObject variable in CmdOnWeaponThrowed function cause Commands do not access objects as parameter.

[image: Error Im getting]

Comment: you have `obj` in the method `CmdOnWeaponThrowed`. Where is the declaration of that GameObject??

Comment: obj is just placeholder I want to understand how to access it, I want to access my throwedObject

Answer (score 0):

Pass it to method:

```
[Command]
void CmdOnWeaponThrowed(GameObject obj)
{
    var netId = obj.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>();
    if (netId == null)
    {
        // component is missing.
        return;
    }
    NetworkServer.Spawn(obj, netId.assetId);
}
```

then

```
void ThrowWeapon(WeaponThrowing weapon)
{
    GameObject throwedObject = (GameObject)Instantiate (weapon.throwObjectPrefab, weaponManager.throwWeaponPlace.position,  weaponManager.throwWeaponPlace.rotation);

    Debug.Log(throwedObject);

    Rigidbody throwedObjectRB = throwedObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();

    if (throwedObjectRB != null) 
    {
        throwedObjectRB.AddForce(throwedObject.transform.forward * weapon.throwForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

    CmdOnWeaponThrowed(throwedObject);
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I already tried that but Command functions only accept basic data types like int, float e.t.c. The parameter turns null and function kicks out an error object reference is not set to an instance of an objects.

Comment: Can you store a reference of the object outside a function when spawning. And later in command you can use it?

Comment: I tried it but it didn't help still kicks out error.

Comment: [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.CommandAttribute.html) say you can pass gameObject with network identity attached. Aren't you supposed to have network identity with the weapon?

Comment: I added link to image with error in the post bottom

Comment: If I add net id to weapon it will give error that net id must be on the root of the object in my case weapon is nested in the player which has net id

Comment: `NetworkServer.Spawn(obj, obj.GetComponent<NetworkIdentity>().assetId);` this is trying to get NetworkIdentity component which is required. Otherwise there will be null ref exception.

Comment: My weapon throw object has an identity it is a bomb prefab with net id so it doesn't have to give null

Comment: so if it has identity why not pass it as a parameter to command?

Comment: try to debug by adding breakpoints and find out what the exception is about.

Comment: Checked out with your version and it still gives same error meaning that obj is null when passed to command and you can't get its net id.

Comment: I cannot find out why it is null.